# Replace substring in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have a following example Dataframe:

```
col1 | col2 | ...  total
------------------------
0,19 | 31  | .... |I need  200,02 euros
0,19 | 40  | .... |I need   10,02 euros
   0 | 20  | .... |I need  150,02 euros
   . | ..  | .... |...
```

I want to replace the numeric values in `total` columns, only if `col2` is 31.

The new numeric values (to be replaced) should be the sum of (`total` * `col1`)+ `total` for rows except `31`. So, the new value in `total` should be ((10.02 * 0.19)+10.02) + ((150.02 * 0)+150.02) = `161.94`. Therefore, the resulting dataframe should be as follows:

```
col1 | col2 | ...  total
------------------------
0,19 | 31  | .... |I need  161,94 euros
0,19 | 40  | .... |I need   10,02 euros
   0 | 20  | .... |I need  150,02 euros
   . | ..  | .... |...
```

I came across [df.iterrows()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), but they explicitly tell us to

> never modify something you are iterating over

So, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First multiple `col1` with `total`, add `total` and filter rows by mask and sum with assign to rows with mask - but first convert values to numeric:

```
m = df.col2.ne(31)

total = df['total'].str.extract('(\d+,\d+)', expand=False).str.replace(',','.').astype(float)

s1 = df['col1'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)

s = s1.mul(total).add(total)

df.loc[~m, 'total'] = f"I need {str(s[m].sum().round(2)).replace('.',',')} euros"

print (df)
   col1  col2                total
0  0,19    31  I need 161,94 euros
1  0,19    40   I need 10,02 euros
2     0    20  I need 150,02 euros
```

Comment: I get `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`, so I did `astype('float')` but this somehow adds $ sign out of nowhere

Comment: `total` in the edited example also adds `$` to the number. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: @francomango - No idea. Btw, input format in `total` column is not like `200,02 euros` ?

Comment: Yes, it has the same format.

Comment: @francomango - hmm, are you sure solution added `$` ? For me not.

Comment: This probably is due the data I have and not your solution.

Comment: Can I solve this without explicitly giving  `f"I need .... euros` because i.) the string is really long and is not same in all rows. It has the amount in the same place tho.

Answer (score 1):

For latter part of your question, all you need to do is create a copy of your dataframe, and use one for the iteration and the other one for the modifications:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'cond'] = # edit the DF
```

Second, I feel like you are overcomplicating way too much yourself on this problem. Why can't you have a column with the `number` total (just a float value, `200.0`) and then another `string` column where you get the full sentence `I need 200.0 euros`?

In any case, you will need to parse your `total` column  in search of the amount.

```
aux = df.loc[df['col2'] == 31]
aux['aux_total'] = # parse the total column and extract the amount
df.loc[
    df['col2'] == 31,
    'total'
] = 'I need %2.1f euros' % ((aux['aux_total']*aux['col1'])+aux['col2'])
```

p.d.: as I can see all the other answers are totally missing the fact the `total` column is a `string`, which has to be replaced. You can't operate with that column as an integer.

Comment: Can I solve this without explicitly giving  `f"I need %2.1f euros ...`  because i.) the string is really long and is not same in all rows. It has the amount in the same place tho.

Comment: @francomango Yes, all you need is to use regex to to find the amount in the string and then replace it with the new value. You can do it using `apply`, so you can use every row `total` string without having to manually type it.